# Drawing in Latex or 3rd party

Tags: circuitikz, tikz-graphdrawing

What sort of program out there would be able to reproduce the following drawings. Can this be done in latex?[image]

[image]

Comment: For electric circuits you can use LaTeX package `circuitikz` (which based on TikZ/PGF) package. Some mechanical system can be relatively small effort drawn by TikZ or similar program PSscript. Other require more effort and skills (experiences) with mentioned program. Look in http://www.texample.net/, maybe you will find something what you like to draw and get a filling, how complicated is drawing your picture with LaTeX.

Comment: There are at least 5 choices: the already mentioned `circuitikz`, `makecirc` (based on MetaPost), `pst-circ` (based on pstricks), `circ` and `circuit-macros` (using the `pic` language).

Comment: there's also `circdia` but the manual is only available in German.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's crude, but I tend to make simple diagrams in PowerPoint and then add LaTeX symbols/ equations etc to it using the add-on [IguanaTex](http://www.jonathanleroux.org/software/iguanatex/). Very easy to use and you can simply insert the finished image into your LaTeX document.